# How to access collections in Firebase Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Ok my question is pretty basic, in my app I have a post system, and in that post you can like the post. So when the user clicks the like button, I want the database to update the likes. Only problem is... I don't know how to capture the collections data [image: firebase data]

This is what the data looks like, its a randomly generated collections id, I tried to set the collections id to the id of the user but that would mean I can't make multiple posts. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Can you share the code that you've tried and then explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can store previous value of likes inside a variable using the get function present in Firestore. Then you can update a field in the Firestore document inside a collection using updateDoc method using the value  as shown below

```
import {
   getFirestore,doc,getDoc,updateDoc
} from 'firebase/firestore';
 
async function updateData() {
  const docRef=doc(db,’collection’,’document’);
 const docData=await getDoc(docRef);
 var value=docData.get('likes');
 updateDoc(docRef,{likes:value+1});
}
 
updateData();
```

Or you can use the increment function present in Firestore. It will increment your field directly and you won’t have to create a variable separately to store the previous value as shown in [Add data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value)

```
import {
   getFirestore,doc,getDoc,updateDoc, increment
} from 'firebase/firestore';

async function updateData() {
  const docRef=doc(db,’collection’,’document’);
  await updateDoc(docRef,{likes:increment(1)});
}
 
updateData();
```

You can learn more about the update() in [Update a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data).

Comment: I should have mentioned im using firebase 7.14.0 in my project...

Comment: Hi, I suggest you to upgrade your firebase version as 7 is too old. You can check out [Upgrade to V9](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) for more details.